# Trailing slash at end of DRF URL give 401

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using Django Rest Framework and Simple JWT for authentication.

I have a problem that the endpoint `posts/`requires authentication, and it doesn't when I don't append a slash at the end of the URL. However, if there is a slash at the end of the URL, then it requires authentication (and when user is not logged in)! Almost all browsers append a trailing slash to URLs (I'm using React + Axios). How do I make my end point work without authentication even when there's a trailing slash?

Comment: It works how we want on safari, but not on chrome or firefox

Comment: How does your URL description for `posts` look like in `urls.py`?